# VLSM Scheme Approach

Tags: cisco, ip

I have been asked this question in a Cisco Packet Tracer. It is testing my knowledge of designing and implementing a vlsm addressing scheme.

The requirements are:

You will subnet the network address 192.168.72.0/24. The network has the following

**Room-114** LAN will require 7 host IP addresses
**Room-279** LAN will require 15 host IP addresses
**Room-312** LAN will require 29 host IP addresses
**Room-407** LAN will require 58 host addresses
Also a serial WAN link that requires addressing

A subnet table is asked for

Here is my solution

[image]

I was hoping someone would review my solution, and raise any problems.

I will have four /26 subnets, and the last one will be subnetted with 4 possible /28 subnets, 3 of which are unused, and 4 possible /30 subnets, 3 of which are still available. The /28 will be used for Room-114 with 7 hosts and the /30 will be used for the WAN with two hosts,

Does my solution abide by general good practices?

Comment: Sadly, questions that ask for opinions are off topic here.  There can be many factors that affect "good" practice.  what's good in one environment may not be for another.  But you can test your subnetting in packet tracer to see if your solution works.

Comment: Sorry, it appears that my ip addressing would work fine, the question required a different approach with its wording, but I completed it successfully, so no need for any advice now. Thanks